# VBA Excel Sending More than one Email

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to write a program that sends different managers emails regaurding their information. For some rease the program will send only one email out and say it is completed with no errors. How do I make it send all 14 emails. Right now the emails are all pointed at my direct email address. Please Help!

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Do While i <> 14
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = SupervisorAddress(i)
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "QTF Expired"
    .Body = Body(i)
    'You can add a file like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0
i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Step through it with `F8`, after the first iteration what happens? Also, remove the `On Error Resume Next` and let us know if any errors are thrown.  Alternatively, do a `For i = 1 to 14 // [your code] // next i` instead of a `While` loop.

Comment: What is `OutMail` ?  Once it's sent the first time, you can't send it again.  You'll need to create a new mail item for each iteration through the loop.  Also this type of loop is exactly what a `For...Next` loop is intended for: using `Do While...Loop` is a bit confusing.

Comment: @TimWilliams Outmail is "Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)"

Comment: @BruceWayne When I ran the program without the On Error Resume I got Run Time Error -2147221238 The Item has been moved or deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 14
    With OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        .to = SupervisorAddress(i)
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "QTF Expired"
        .Body = Body(i)
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Tangential question - I personally prefer the `For x = y to z` loop over a `Do while ...` loop. I notice you switched the `while` loop out for a `for` loop -- is that personal preference as well, or are there performance or some other differences too?

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne - I noticed your comment after I'd posted mine on the same topic.  I guess it's just convention to use a `For...Next` when the number of iterations is pre-determined as in this case.  `Do While...Loop` is better suited when the number of iterations is determined only as the loop iterates.